# Как синхронизировать две TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

Имеются 2 TextView: inText и outText.
В inText пишу строку, и он должен сразу же появиться в outText. Листнер надо повесить что ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно добавить Listener. А конкретнее `inText.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher)`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

В `afterTextChanged()` просто делаем `outText.setText(inText.getText().toString())`.